# Polymer app-localize-behavior ?lang=en parameter

Tags: url, parameters, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm building a Polymer app using the app-localize-behavior element. Is there a way to bind URL parameters for the language like `example.com?lang=en` ?

Thanks for your help!

Nicolai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use [`iron-location`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-location) and the included `iron-query-params` to parse the location and return a bindable value for you.

Something like this:

```
<iron-location query="{{queryString}}"></iron-location>

<iron-query-params params-string="[[queryString]]"
                   params-object="{{params}}></iron-query-params>
```

`params.lang` will then have your language parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Works!